# SKAction Parabola Movement

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I'm working in Sprite Kit and I'm trying to make a sprite move from one point to another. Currently, I am able to do this with SkAction.moveTo and the sprite moves in a straight line. However, I'm curious as to if it would be possible for the sprite to move in a parabola instead of a straight line as it reaches its destination. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You can construct any CGPath and then use SKAction.followPath to send it along that path.

Comment: How exactly would I make a parabola with CGPath?

Comment: Either use the equation of a parabola to generate points and add them to the CGPath or calculate the control points for a Bézier curve like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/336679 and use it to make a CGPath

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple way to create a parabolic UIBezierPath:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPointZero)
path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200))
```

This looks like this when graphed in a Playground:

[image]

For your sprite to move with this path, use this code:

```
mySprite.runAction(SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, duration: 1.0))
```

To fine-tune the parabola, change the constants in the code above to change the path.

Comment: I tried that, but the ball just flies off the screen and I don't really understand why. This is what it is right now: `var controlPoint = CGPointMake((ball.position.x+location.x)/2, (ball.position.y+location.y)/2)
        
            var ballPath = UIBezierPath()
            ballPath.moveToPoint(ball.position)
            ballPath.addQuadCurveToPoint(location, controlPoint: CGPointZero)`

Comment: @Comrod33 The only thing I can think of is that your physics world/engine are causing this behavior.

Comment: Happens the same to me. In objective C, no physics added to project, just using `[SKAction followPath: duration:]`, the resulting position is just enormous (while i am not using such big numbers...)

Answer (score 0):

I've been drawn quite awhile in this problem. I would like to share a bit about my experience about parabola movement in SKAction.

This is the code for **Swift 3**

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 200))

let parabolaAction = SKAction.follow(path.cgPath, duration: 1)
```

Your Sprite Node must have been placed in a certain position.

**The second line** means that the Sprite Node will move by x:0 and y:0. It's a relative movement. The problem why I'm struggling was considering that the Point is the new absolute position. But it's not.

**The third line** means that the Sprite Node will move by x:100, y:0 into a new position with the help of control point. Control point is the top coordinate like what *erdekhayser* shows.

If you set points in path with Sprite Node position + certain value then your Sprite Node might be positioned off the scene.

Hope this helps understanding UIBezierPath for parabola movement.